# Library for a popular programming language to show an updating linear chart

Tags: open-source, graphs

I am looking for a library for a popular programming language (Java, Ruby, Python, C etc) to show a changing linear graph, displayed as a part of GUI.

Other part of program would continue to supply data what should be used to display graph that would continue to update, without interaction from user. I would expect displayed graph to look more or less like following image:

[image: example graph]

(graph is from http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~msmith27/readings/public/nowak-1993a.pdf)

I want it for "a popular programming language" as it would be only part of program and I am not interested in using something like [NetLogo](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/PDBasicEvolutionary).

For reference - I want to make a program that would visualise spatial prisoner's dilemma ([Lindgren's Model](https://books.google.pl/books?id=eUoolrxSFy0C&pg=PA227&dq=%22Combining%20the%20Game%20of%20Life%20and%20the%20Prisoner%27s%20Dilemma%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MqVgVdauAom9ygPp-oOgAw&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Combining%20the%20Game%20of%20Life%20and%20the%20Prisoner%27s%20Dilemma%22&f=false)) - basically combining Game of Life and the Prisoner's Dilemma.

related to [Software/library for generation and real-time updating of network graph (nodes and edges) on website with MySql data](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10470/software-library-for-generation-and-real-time-updating-of-network-graph-nodes-a) but I want avoid displaying graph on a website and I strongly prefer to not use a database.

My main additional requirement is that it should be open-source. I would prefer a maintained library or at least one that is finished and with a good documentation.